# SyntaxError: Unexpected token in Gulpfile.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules, package.json

**In My  Gulpfile.js faulty part:**

```
gulp.task('webpack', gulp.series(async () => {
    const option = yargs.argv.release ? "-p" : "-d";
    execSync(`node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js ${option}`, {
        stdio: [null, process.stdout, process.stderr]
    });
}));
```

**My package.json:**

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "npm run package-dev",
    "package-dev": "node ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js",
    "package-release": "node ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js --release"
  },
  "Dependencies": {
    "@types/applicationinsights-js": "^1.0.5",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.41",
    "@types/knockout": "^3.4.40",
    "@types/react": "^16.0.40",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.1",
    "@types/requirejs": "^2.1.28",
    "del": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-inline-source": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-tslint": "^8.1.1",
    "office-ui-fabric-react": "^4.5.0",
    "promise-polyfill": "^8.1.0",
    "requirejs": "^2.3.2",
    "ts-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "tslint": "^5.4.3",
    "typescript": "^3.1.6",
    "vss-web-extension-sdk": "^5.141.0",
    "webpack": "^4.26.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
  },
  "name": "task-group",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.7.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@uifabric/utilities": "^7.2.0",
    "react": "^16.9.0"
  },
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

I running **`npm install`** and get the following error.

**In Terminal Screen:**

> gulp.task('webpack', gulp.series(async () => {
>                                              ^
>       SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
>           at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
>           at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
>           at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>           at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>           at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>           at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>           at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
>           at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>           at execute (C:\Users\Ece\Documents\Projects\Links-Group\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\versioned\^4.0.0\index
>       .js:36:18)
>           at Liftoff.handleArguments (C:\Users\Ece\Documents\Projects\Links-Group\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\gulp-cli\index.js:2
>       01:24)

Comment: What about double tilda `` chars in the end of the line starting with `const option...` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run the following commands respectively solved the problem.

```
npm rm -rf node_modules

npm install
```